# TensorFlow iOS memory warnings

Tags: ios, memory, machine-learning, tensorflow

We are building an iOS app to perform image classification using the TensorFlow library.

Using our machine learning model (91MB, 400 classes) and the TensorFlow 'simple' example, we get memory warnings on any iOS device with 1GB of RAM. 2GB models do not experience any warnings, while < 1GB models completely run out of memory and crash the app.

We are using the latest TensorFlow code from the master branch that includes [this iOS memory performance commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/459c2fed498530b794c4871892fd68d1e6834ac6), which we thought might help but didn't.

We have also tried setting various GPU options on our TF session object, including `set_allow_growth(true)` and `set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction()`.

Our only changes to the TF 'simple' example code is a `wanted_width` and `wanted_height` of 299, and an `input_mean` and `input_std` of 128.

Has anyone else run into this? Is our model simply too big?

Answer (score 0):

You can use memory mapping, have you tried that? Tensorflow provides documentation. You can also round your weight values to even less decimal places.

Comment: I never followed up on this question, but I did end up using an mmapped model and it solved the issue. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @azdev could you give more details about how you got mmapped model?